# Disable keycloak on vuejs on test environment (development) only

Tags: vue.js, keycloak

I have on VueJS project, this configuration :

```
let initOptions = {
    url: 'http://localhost:81/auth', realm: 'cmt', clientId: 'cmt_api', onLoad: 'login-required'
}

let keycloak = Keycloak(initOptions)

const routes = [
        { path: '/', name: 'MyFirstRoute', component: MyFirstRoute },
        { path: '/SecondWindow', name: 'SecondWindow', component: SecondWindow },
        { path: '/ThirdWindow', name: 'ThirdWindow', component: ThirdWindow },
        { path: '*', redirect: '/', },
]

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes
})

const app = new Vue({vuetify,router,i18n,render: h => h(App)}).$mount('#app')

keycloak.init({ onLoad: initOptions.onLoad }).then(
(auth) => {
    if (!auth) {
        window.location.reload();
    } else {
        // Vue.$log.info("Authenticated");
       app
    }
}
)
```

I want to use this configuration for Production, Acceptance, Docker testing but for the development testing only, I would like don't use keycloak.
Unfortunately, I don't find some responses. I create (for dev ) in environment variable the boolean VUE_APP_DEV=true.

Can somebody help me to complete the code to allow to connect to the application (without keycloak) without change the code (comment the keycloak reference in the main.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `process.env.NODE_ENV`, it will be equal to `'production'` when run on production, and equal to `'development'` when run on dev env - so for you code:

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
   let keycloak = Keycloak(initOptions);
   keycloak.init({ onLoad: initOptions.onLoad }).then((auth) => {
    if (!auth) {
        window.location.reload();
    } else {
        // Vue.$log.info("Authenticated");
       app
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. 
````js
  const KEYCLOAK_DISABLED = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';
  if (KEYCLOAK_DISABLED) {
    app
  } else {
    keycloak.init({ onLoad: initOptions.onLoad }).then(
    ( auth) => {
        if (!auth) {
            window.location.reload();
        } else {
           app
        }
    }
    )
  }
````